# DateTime strange error

Tags: asp.net, localization

```
DateTime? billDateFrom = string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtBillDateFrom.Text) ? null : (DateTime?)DateTime.Parse(txtBillDateFrom.Text);
```

txtBillDateFrom.Text equals "05/26/2011". (26 may 2011)

This code throws an error "String was not recognized as a valid DateTime" only in a web application. In a console application it works good.
Why? Does it depend on locale?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, the behavior of [Parse()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1k1skd40.aspx) depends on the current thread's culture. You can use [ParseExact()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss.aspx) to make that behavior consistent, regardless of that culture:

```
DateTime.ParseExact(txtBillDateFrom.Text, "d", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

Comment: Well, that's a bit misleading. Not all overloads of `Parse` does depend on the current culture. You don't have to use `ParseExact` to specify a culture.

Comment: @Guffa, you're right, but no overload of `Parse()` allows you to specify a format string. Since I was aiming for consistent behavior, I went for `ParseExact()` and the `d` format string instead. Good point nonetheless :)

Answer (score 2):

Yes it does. You can change thread's culture, or get a `CultureInfo` for a desired locale and pass its `DateTimeFormat` to `DateTime.Parse`

```
// Setting in thread
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US");
DateTime dt1 = DateTime.Parse("05/26/2011");
// Only for 1 parse
DateTime dt2 = DateTime.Parse("05/26/2011", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US").DateTimeFormat);
```

Also I beleive you can set the culture in asp.net application's settings.

```
<system.web>
    <globalization culture="en-US"/>
</system.web>
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it depends on locale.

You can specify the locale that you want to use in the `web.config` file, or you can specify it in the call to `Parse`:`

```
DateTime.Parse(txtBillDateFrom.Text, CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-GB"))
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends on current culture. In web.config you can set needed culture:

```
<globalization uiCulture="it" culture="it-IT" />
```

Answer (score -2):

Try Below

```
 DateTime dt;
        DateTime.TryParse("05/26/2011", out dt);
```